# 3.3V Regulator Overheating

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, 3.3v

Here is my circuit
[image]

For some reason my 3.3v regulator is over heating. The regulator is a [TLV1117LV33](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/texas-instruments/tlv1117lv33dcyr/?qs=tEz3BkPb1rwzXMb8FiWhow%3D%3D&countrycode=US&currencycode=USD). I've tried everything to try and debug the problem but can't seem to figure out what's wrong except maybe a short to ground somewhere on my board.

I've connected just a MicroUSB cable to the regulator and even that is causing it to overheat.

Could it be because of the capacitors I have on there?

Comment: Did you measure 3V3 to GND to check whether there is a short or not? What is the actual output voltage?

Comment: Double check the pinout of the regulator.

Comment: _”except maybe a short to ground somewhere on my board”_ This should be your first suspect.

Comment: What is Vcc? If you are expecting the regulator to do a lot then it will get hot.

Comment: What kind of capacitors are C5 and C6?

Comment: You said your regulator is TLV1117LV33. Your schematic doesn't match its pinout. Pin 1 should be ground, pin 2 (and tab) is output, pin 3 is input.

Comment: First clue.  Does LED come on?  No.  Odds are regulator is not regulating!

Comment: @td127 I've been doing this for 4 decades, and I still get caught out with non-standard pinouts! , The negative regulators are usually tab = substrate = most negative voltage, I think some of the LDO regulators must use Ptype technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @td127 pointed out , the pinout is non standard. See annotated diagram below.

[image: LDO block diagram]

With LDO's the series pass element is a PNP bipolar or PMOS transistor, both of these are grown from P type substrate, and the substrate is connected to the tab (the block of silicon inside the device has it's back face soldered to the tab , for heat dissipation).  If you look at PNP and PMOS power transistors, the collector (drain) is always connected to the substrate. The LDO is just a PNP or PMOS transistor, with some extra circuitry attached to the base (gate).

Answer (score 1):

@td127 was correct. I mismatched my voltage regulator with my footprint.... Double check your work before having PCBs made..

Comment: First clue.  Does LED come on?  No.  Odds are regulator is not regulating!